# Woher kommt die Redewendung „etwas auf sich nehmen“?

Tags: word-usage, idiom

> Ich habe den weiten Weg nach Deutschland auf mich genommen.

Ich kenne die Bedeutung, aber die Frage ist hier, warum es *auf mich* heißt. Ich nehme an, dass diese Redewendung etwas mit der Religion und Jesus Christus zu tun hat, weil er sein Kreuz auf sich genommen hatte?

Comment: Könntest du diese Frage verallgemeinern? Die Redewendung "etwas auf sich nehmen" ist immerhin ganz allgemein verwendbar, nicht nur in Verbindung mit einem weiten Weg.

Comment: Hier steht was zu "eine Last auf sich nehmen" http://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=~~etwas+auf+sich+nehmen&bool=relevanz&suchspalte[]=rart_ou

Comment: "Darauf sagte Jesus zu seinen Jüngern: Wer mein Jünger sein will, verleugne sich selbst, nehme sein Kreuz auf sich und folge mir nach. Denn wer sein Leben retten will, wird es verlieren; wer aber sein Leben um meinetwillen verliert, wird es gewinnen" (Mt 16,25). Kreuz wird substituiert durch "die Reise" usgl - also deine Last.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Im eigentlichen Wortsinn bedeutet »*auf sich nehmen*«, dass man etwas schweres, also eine Last, trägt. (Entweder auf den Schultern, auf dem Rücken oder auf den Armen).

Wenn die schwere Last nicht in Kilogramm gemessen werden kann, sondern wenn es sich um eine schwere Aufgabe handelt, handelt es sich - im übertragenen Sinn - ebenfalls um eine Last, und die kann man eben - wieder im übertragenen Sinn - ebenfalls auf sich nehmen.

Da der Weg nach Deutschland hier sogar ausdrücklich als »*weit*« beschrieben wird, darf der Weg als beschwerlich (also als schwer, und somit als eine Last) angesehen werden. Und diese Last kann man *auf sich nehmen*.